# Mining the Social Web example1-6: List comprehension

Tags: python, list, twitter, list-comprehension

Here is the code:

```
import twitter
twitter_search = twitter.Twitter(domain="search.twitter.com")
search_results = []
for page in range(1,6):
    search_results.append(twitter_search.search(q="SNL", rpp=100, page=page))

tweets = [ r['text']\
           for results in search_results \
           for r in result['results']]
```

my error reads:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/owner1/Documents/ex17.py", line 9, in <module>
    for r in result['results']]
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

How can I fix this? I've tried subbing 'results' out for an integer, 1, but that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

There is a typo in:

```
tweets = [ r['text']\
           for results in search_results \
           for r in result['results']]
```

`result` is not consistent with the `results` used in the same loop:

```
tweets = [ r['text']\
           for result in search_results \
           for r in result['results']]
```

works for me at least.

Answer (score 0):

What is `result`? You have `results` from `search_results`, but I see no `result` in there.

Comment: Not sure. I am taking the code directly from the book.  Can you recommend what I should assign to result?

Comment: @LNA: you probably have a typo there